# Why do I get a Visualforce error when pressing enter key in html input textbox?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have an input textbox with a jQuery button.  When the button is clicked, I get the desired output.  When the user enters something in the textbox and presses 'Enter' then I get a visualforce error.  There error is self explanatory but can't seem to figure out what is causing it.  Any insight or ideas on how to debug this would be tremendous.

> **Visualforce Error:**  The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique,
>   and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two
>   consecutive underscores.

Sample Code:

```
<script>

  $j( "#btn" ).button().on( "click", function() {
     var myVal = document.getElementById("myField").value; 
     // Do cool stuff here.
    });

</script>

<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

// Pressing enter here will cause error.

I should mention I tried to capture keydown event but keep getting the same error.

******************* Bizarre Workaround ***************

```
<form action="formprocessor.html" method="get" id="postForm">
    <fieldset>  
      <p><label class="field" for="myField"><span>*</span>myField Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="myField"/></p>
      <input type="text" id="RandomField" style="display:none"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

This is very bizarre.  Adding another input field fixes the issue. This code is contained in a visualforce component.  I have another component that functions just fine (the other component has multiple input fields).  Why would a second input field with `style="display:none"` fix the error?

Comment: I think it would help if you could paste the entire page's code. Do you have any other button defined with type="submit" on the page?

Comment: Its hard to say whats going on without seeing your full code.  My advise would we to comment out unrelated things on your page until your can be sure of where the error is coming from.

Comment: @AAU  Take a quick glance at my modified post.  I don't want to post full code because it's quite extensive.  It seems adding another input field fixes the issue.  Any insight as to why adding another input field fixed the issue?  Also, regarding buttons.  Since this is a modal dialog in a VF component, I have 3 buttons.  1 to open dialog, 1 to submit, 1 to close dialog.